# How to access a function defined as key of an object from within another function defined as key of same object in JS

Tags: javascript, functional-programming, javascript-objects

Given below code, I need to reuse functionality from `innerFunc1` and `innerFunc2` in `innerfunc3`, but I am not sure, how `innerFunc1` and `innerFunc2` can be accessed inside `innerfunc3`, because those are not even defined at the time. Also, I am wondering, is there a better pattern to achieve this functionality?

```
const outerFunc = () => ({
    innerFunc1: () => {
        console.log("Inner function 1");
    },
    innerFunc2: () => {
        console.log("Inner function 2");
    },
    innerFunc3: () => {
        innerFunc1();
        innerFunc2();
        console.log("Inner function 3");
    }
});

const func = outerFunc();
func.innerFunc3();
```

**Expected behaviour**

```
Inner function 1
Inner function 2
Inner function 3
```

But apparent output is `ReferenceError: innerFunc1 is not defined`

**Update:**

It occurred to me that desired output can be achieved using below code

```
const outerFunc = () => ({
    innerFunc1: () => {
        console.log("Inner function 1");
    },
    innerFunc2: () => {
        console.log("Inner function 2");
    },
    innerFunc3: () => {
        const func = outerFunc();
        func.innerFunc1();
        func.innerFunc2();
        console.log("Inner function 3");
    }
});

const func = outerFunc();
func.innerFunc3();
```

But, is it the right pattern to use?

Comment: Is there any reason why you don't use ES classes here?

Comment: If you change it to use regular functions instead of arrow functions you can use `this`.

Comment: @Temoncher, original code is legacy, I just need to add ```innerFunc3``` that uses ```innerFunc2``` functionality. Can't really change anything about it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## ES Classes solution

`class` + `this` keyword

```js
class Func {
    innerFunc1 = () => {
        console.log("Inner function 1");
    }
    innerFunc2 = () => {
        console.log("Inner function 2");
    }
    innerFunc3 = () => {
        this.innerFunc1();
        this.innerFunc2();
        console.log("Inner function 3");
    }
}

const func = new Func();
func.innerFunc3();
```

BUT, as @Sergey pointed out right

> Assigning functions to class properties is not considered to be a good practice since it will duplicate this logic each time an instance is created. Instead it should be defined as a regular method and thus one method will be shared with N instances through the prototype

## Solution without classes

factory function + `this` keyword

```js
const outerFunc = () => ({
    innerFunc1: function() {
        console.log("Inner function 1");
    },
    innerFunc2: function() {
        console.log("Inner function 2");
    },
    innerFunc3: function() {
        this.innerFunc1();
        this.innerFunc2();
        console.log("Inner function 3");
    }
});

const func = outerFunc();
func.innerFunc3();
```

It works because of the normal vs arrow function [difference when working with function invocation context](https://betterprogramming.pub/difference-between-regular-functions-and-arrow-functions-f65639aba256).

In case of a normal function `this` will be a reference to a `func`, because it is determined on call and the call happens on `func` object.

In case of an arrow function `this` will be `undefined`, because an arrow function infers it's context on it's creation when the object is not yet instantiated.

Comment: Assigning functions to class properties is not considered to be a good practice since it will duplicate this logic each time an instance is created. Instead it should be defined as a regular method and thus one method will be shared with N instances through the prototype

Comment: Yes, @Sergey, you are right about this detail. I just wanted to show that it is possible with arrow functions too.

Comment: @Sergey it doesn't really matter in this scenario, OP is recreating the functions on every call.

Comment: Thanks @Temoncher, I can use the "Solution without classes" in my particular scenario.

Answer (score 1):

If for whatever reason you must use arrow functions instead of regular functions. You can use a closure to store the object.

```
const outerFunc = () => {
    let obj = {
        innerFunc1: () => {
            console.log("Inner function 1");
        },
        innerFunc2: () => {
            console.log("Inner function 2");
        },
        innerFunc3: () => {
            obj.innerFunc1();
            obj.innerFunc2();
            console.log("Inner function 3");
       }
    };
    return obj;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Another solution with keeping use of arrow functions would be to define functions as variables and return as an object at the end. This will also eliminate the need to use `this` keyword for other function invocations.

```
const outerFunc = () => {
    const innerFunc1 = () => {
        console.log("Inner function 1");
    };

    const innerFunc2 = () => {
        console.log("Inner function 2");
    };

    const innerFunc3 = () => {
        innerFunc1();
        innerFunc2();
        console.log("Inner function 3");
    };
    return {
        innerFunc1,
        innerFunc2,
        innerFunc3
    };
};

const func = outerFunc();
func.innerFunc3();
```